# Ubuntu 20.10: Software installer installs x86-64 binary of Signal Desktop on Raspberry Pi

Tags: snap, raspberrypi, bug-reporting, 20.10

Is there a fix?

```
jpo@jpo-pi-ubuntu:~$ signal-desktop 
/snap/signal-desktop/296/snap/command-chain/desktop-launch: line 543: /snap/signal-desktop/296/opt/Signal/signal-desktop: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
/snap/signal-desktop/296/snap/command-chain/desktop-launch: line 543: /snap/signal-desktop/296/opt/Signal/signal-desktop: Success
jpo@jpo-pi-ubuntu:~$ file /snap/signal-desktop/296/opt/Signal/signal-desktop
/snap/signal-desktop/296/opt/Signal/signal-desktop: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=cc24f25f5633f1b4ac1a156a7d84fc2e363bf4ee, stripped
jpo@jpo-pi-ubuntu:~$ arch
aarch64
jpo@jpo-pi-ubuntu:~$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=groovy
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.10"
jpo@jpo-pi-ubuntu:~$ snap list
Name               Version                     Rev   Tracking         Publisher     Notes
chromium           86.0.4240.198               1406  latest/stable    canonical✓    -
core18             20200929                    1936  latest/stable    canonical✓    base
gnome-3-28-1804    3.28.0-19-g98f9e67.98f9e67  147   latest/stable    canonical✓    -
gnome-3-34-1804    0+git.3556cb3               61    latest/stable/…  canonical✓    -
gtk-common-themes  0.1-36-gc75f853             1506  latest/stable/…  canonical✓    -
signal-desktop     1.30.0                      296   latest/edge      snapcrafters  -
snap-store         3.36.0-81-gc9eee2f          476   latest/stable/…  canonical✓    -
snapd              2.47.1                      9730  latest/stable    canonical✓    snapd
```

Comment: Thanks, but this only allows to report legal problems, not technical ones.

Comment: `snap info signal-desktop` includes the URL to report bugs.

Comment: Seems to be a known problem. See https://github.com/snapcrafters/signal-desktop/issues/38

I just added my observations: https://github.com/snapcrafters/signal-desktop/issues/38#issuecomment-731619489

Comment: Voting to close: Bugs should be discussed on the upstream bug report (not AskUbuntu). We can help you troubleshoot to determine if a problem is a bug...but you already know that it is a bug.